# Can't Load URL Error occurs when login in with Facebook(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I could pass through Facebook login in development but credentials error prevents from passing in *production*.

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I have entered my domain into the App domain and input redirect URL also.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZHuu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFKLJ.png)

Comment: If you get this after the login dialog, in the step where the code gets exchanged for a token, then this means you passed a different `redirect_uri` value with that API call, than in the login dialog call. The value must be identical for both.

Comment: Thanks so much. I fixed Devise error.